# MySQL error messages cut off

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I'm using SphinxSE as a data source in MySQL.  I've running a query which produces an error but the error message is truncated before the vital part:

> ERROR 1430 (HY000): There was a problem processing the query on the foreign data source. Data source error: searchd error: index myindex1: parse error: unknown identifier '

The error message should read `unknown identifier 'mycolumn'`.

How can I get the rest of the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the full text of the message is getting logged to /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log, which is sufficient for now.